Mean, variance and convergence of stochastic processes
Suppose I have some random process, where I initialize two empty arrays A:[], B:[]. Following, elements sampled from $N(0,1)$ are allocated to $A$ or $B$, Every time, an element is sampled, it is compared to the means, $\mu_A, \mu_B$. Whichever mean is further from the sampled value, the corresponding array receives the allocated value.
Through simulations, I've observed that the difference between means converges on zero, with less variance than in comparison, when sampled units are randomly allocated to $A,B$ with equal/uniform probability of assignment.
Is there a name for such a random process? And are analytic solutions to its long-term behavior available rather than by purely through simulations?
Edit: the means are initialized to 0 each. And the probabilities of assignment to A,B are proportional to element distances from the means. Rather than hard assignment.

"Proportional to element distances from the means" is difficult to follow, because it sounds impossible.  Could you clarify that?  Are you perhaps trying to specify that the random value $Z$ is assigned to $A$ with probability $|Z-\mu_A| / (|Z-\mu_A| + |Z-\mu_B|)$?

@whuber exactly, thank you for bridging that gap!
